# Changing the structure of a function with if statement Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement, module

There is the function a could either be in the form of `client.LinearKline.LinearKline_get()` or in the form of `client.Kline.Kline_get()`. How could I make a and b modular so that both options could work the function below does not really work.

```
if choice ==1:
    a= LinearKline
    b= LinearKline_get
else:
    a= Kline
    b= Kline_get

client.a.b()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can also use `getattr` for this.

```
if choice == 1:
    a = "LinearKline"
    b = "LinearKline_get"
else:
    a = "Kline"
    b = "Kline_get"

getattr(getattr(client, a), b)()
```

Comment: actually instead of `a` and `b` could I write it as `a="LinearKline.LinearKline_get"`?

Comment: @tonyselcuk why don't you try it yourself and tell us!

Comment: I tried to do `getattr(client, a)()` but its giving me an error

Comment: maybe because ```a``` might not be a function.

Comment: `a` is `a` and `b` combined your function works I am just trying to make it simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the `client` variable you can directly pick the function you need to call:

```py
if choice == 1:
    f = client.LinearKline.LinearKline_get
else:
    f = Kline.Kline_get

f()
```