# Structure of a function altered by if statement Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, if-statement

There is the function a could either be in the form of `client.LinearKline.LinearKline_get()` or in the form of `client.Kline.Kline_get()`. `a` and `b`, `(first_run)` however the `a`,`(second_run)` does not work. `c` just combines `a` and `b` and is simplifies it. My previous post: [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67289620/changing-the-structure-of-a-function-with-if-statement-python) . How would I be able to make 'c' work with `getattr`.

```
choice= 1

if choice == 1:
    a = "LinearKline"
    b = "LinearKline_get"
    c = "LinearKline.LinearKline_get"
else:
    a = "Kline"
    b = "Kline_get"
    c = "Kline.Kline_get"

first_run =getattr(getattr(client, a), b)()
second_run= getattr(client, c)()
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it that way.  It's just the wrong path, and it will be unmaintainable in the long run..

```
def getChoice(client):
    if choice == 1:
        return client.LinearKline.LinearKline_get
    else:
        return client.Kline.Kline_get

first_run = getChoice(client)()
second_run= getChoice(client)()
```

Comment: There are times when OP's general approach will be the right thing to do, and the process of creating a minimal reproducible example can obscure the justification for doing it. That said, it's worth pointing out that it's possible to store e.g. `x = client.Kline.Kline_get` and then have `first_run = x()`.